# Tensorflow not able to choose GPU even though GPU is recognised

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, deep-learning

## I tried to set up tensorflow to run with my GPU (GTX 1070).

1. I installed the latest nvidia drivers `546.29-desktop-win10-win11-64bit-international-dch-whql.exe`

Output from `nvidia-sim`

```bash
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 546.29                 Driver Version: 546.29       CUDA Version: 12.3     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                     TCC/WDDM  | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070      WDDM  | 00000000:05:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   61C    P0              37W / 230W |   1714MiB /  8192MiB |      1%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

2. In order to use the GPU I followed the [Tensorflow Installation Guide for Docker](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker)

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu

WORKDIR /tf-gpu

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8888

ENTRYPOINT [ "jupyter", "lab", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--allow-root", "--no-browser" ]
```

This is my docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
version: '1.0'
services:
  jupyter-lab:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    volumes:
      - ./tf-gpu:/tf-gpu
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              count: 1
              capabilities: [gpu]
```

This is the requirements.txt (I wanted jupyterlab to run on the container)

```
jupyterlab
pandas
matplotlib
```

## First problem indication (maybe ?)

Now after starting this container with `docker-compose up` I imported tensorflow in an .ipynb file and got the following error

```py
import tensorflow as tf
```

```
2023-12-07 23:53:31.948645: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9261] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
2023-12-07 23:53:31.948714: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:607] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2023-12-07 23:53:31.949559: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1515] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2023-12-07 23:53:31.955580: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
```

I am running a Ryzen 5 3600. I do not know if that is of relevance.

## Real problem

Then I tried to see if the GPU gets recognized.

```py
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
tf.config.list_logical_devices()
```

```
Num GPUs Available:  1

2023-12-08 00:04:28.072720: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:887] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-12-08 00:04:28.105405: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:887] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-12-08 00:04:28.105450: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:887] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-12-08 00:04:28.107896: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:887] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-12-08 00:04:28.107935: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:887] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-12-08 00:04:28.107952: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:887] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-12-08 00:04:28.307162: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:887] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-12-08 00:04:28.307210: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:887] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-12-08 00:04:28.307218: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:2022] Could not identify NUMA node of platform GPU id 0, defaulting to 0.  Your kernel may not have been built with NUMA support.
2023-12-08 00:04:28.307249: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:887] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-12-08 00:04:28.307745: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1929] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6731 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0, compute capability: 6.1

[LogicalDevice(name='/device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'),
 LogicalDevice(name='/device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

Evidently the GPU does get recognized

However, when I am running this

```py
with tf.device('/device:GPU:1'):
    a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
    b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])

    # Run on the GPU
    c = tf.matmul(a, b)
    print(c)
```

No runtime error happens??

Also, when I am trying to train any kind of model the speed of training is about the same when I am training on my laptop with no GPU and an Intel i7-1165G7 @ 2.80 GHz.

For example the mnist example

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

# Load MNIST dataset
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

# Preprocessing the data
train_images = train_images.reshape((train_images.shape[0], 28, 28, 1))
test_images = test_images.reshape((test_images.shape[0], 28, 28, 1))

# Normalize pixel values to be between 0 and 1
train_images, test_images = train_images / 255.0, test_images / 255.0

# Convert labels to one-hot encoding
train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)

# Build the model
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels), epochs=5)

# Evaluate the model
model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
```

Produces this output and takes about the same time as on my laptop

```
Num GPUs Available:  1

Epoch 1/5
2023-12-08 00:16:20.796334: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:454] Loaded cuDNN version 8906
2023-12-08 00:16:21.312037: I external/local_xla/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7efafe8c24a0 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2023-12-08 00:16:21.312088: I external/local_xla/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070, Compute Capability 6.1
2023-12-08 00:16:21.328170: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tensorflow/utils/dump_mlir_util.cc:269] disabling MLIR crash reproducer, set env var `MLIR_CRASH_REPRODUCER_DIRECTORY` to enable.
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
I0000 00:00:1701994581.439258     134 device_compiler.h:186] Compiled cluster using XLA!  This line is logged at most once for the lifetime of the process.
1875/1875 [==============================] - 15s 7ms/step - loss: 0.1586 - accuracy: 0.9532 - val_loss: 0.0587 - val_accuracy: 0.9805
Epoch 2/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 13s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0553 - accuracy: 0.9826 - val_loss: 0.0558 - val_accuracy: 0.9809
Epoch 3/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 14s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0379 - accuracy: 0.9883 - val_loss: 0.0408 - val_accuracy: 0.9862
Epoch 4/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 15s 8ms/step - loss: 0.0258 - accuracy: 0.9919 - val_loss: 0.0450 - val_accuracy: 0.9844
Epoch 5/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 14s 8ms/step - loss: 0.0174 - accuracy: 0.9945 - val_loss: 0.0446 - val_accuracy: 0.9864
313/313 [==============================] - 2s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0446 - accuracy: 0.9864

[0.044628895819187164, 0.9864000082015991]
```

I am absolutely clueless how to fix this problem.
Thanks for any help in advance.